# How to fix Gradle in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use android studio 3.6 32 bit
but my Gradle is not working:

Gradle sync failed: Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.6.1).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.6.1/crash-26.6.1.jar

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (54 s 595 ms)

I installed Gradle online and offline but it is not working

Comment: Have you upgraded your build tools properly?

Comment: how to do it? from which part should I upgrade?

Comment: Go to Settings>SDK and check whichever needs update, please update it